# How to get a particular object from the ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, iterator

I have an arraylist

```
 private ArrayList<UserModel> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

the UserModel class contains values for

```
private String email_id, name_id, aboutme;
private Selections mypassions, myinterests;
HashMap<String, String> myworks;
long last_viewed_registerd_timeset;
private Object reg_time1 = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

I pass the arraylist from one class to another.

1. In the other class i am getting the count of arraylists -" userList " as correct.

But i dont know how to take each object from the userlist.

I need to take "reg_time1 " from each list.

how can we do that.can any one suggest the idea to do that

Comment: your question is quite confusing though. you want the item count of userLists or the count of userLists ?. and you can take out easily the count by using loops to iterate in the list.

Comment: @Umair i have certain objects in that array list , how to take only one particular object from the array list

Comment: you just need a loop and an if condition to do that. Basic java bro :)

Comment: you can pass one object too through intent no need to pass whole arraylist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate ArrayList using for loop.

Example: `"ArrayList< UserModel >userList"` is your **UserModel** array list and also write getter setter methods in your **UserModel** class

```
for(int i=0;i< userList.size();i++)
{

    userList.get(i).getReg_time1();
}
```

Here `"getReg_time1()"` is getter method which you have to write in your **UserModel** class.

Answer (score 1):

Make setter - getter of your variables on userModel class and then iterate normally using for loop

class UserModel

```
setRegTime1(Object object){ reg_time1 = object;}
Object getRegTime1(){ return this.reg_time1;}

for(int i =0 ; i < userList.size();i++)
userList.get(i).getRegTime1(); // get time from getter of specific index.
```

Its very basic question so please do read java basics.